# Search both exact and partial match based on a table value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two table in access, 'ITK' and 'Table1', Im looking to search for Table1.itk values in ITK.itk. If both the values match, the result should pull the value from ITK.itk and display "Match", if not, it should search and match similar values (multipel results) from ITK.itk.

This is the code i have made and it is not pulling any results and im not sure what is that im doing wrong or is even possible in access.

```
SELECT Table1.product, Table1.itk, ITK.itk
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     ITK
     ON Table1.itk = ITK.itk
WHERE (((ITK.itk) Like "*[Table1].[itk]"));
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is unlikely to return any results because records will only be returned when the field `ITK.itk` ends with the literal string `"[Table1].[itk]"` (note that this is *not* using the *value* of the `[Table1].[itk]` field.

Assuming I've correctly understood what you're looking to achieve, the following code may perform as required:

```
select 
    table1.product, 
    table1.itk, 
    itk.itk, 
    iif(table1.itk=itk.itk,"Match","Partial Match") as matchtype
from 
    table1 inner join itk on itk.itk like "*" & table1.itk
```

Comment: Quick question, next to like statement, can we add multiple search criteria?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it; it depends on what you are looking to add - a `where` clause may be more appropriate.